# small inexpensive battery powerable component for daily timer circuit with LED and button

Tags: led, timer, battery-operated, rtc

I want to make a small "visual alarm" device that turns on a LED every day at a time (e.g. 17:00) and turns the LED off on button press or (if no button was pressed) at a later time (e.g. 22:00).

I have made something like that on a Raspberry Pi 2. But I now want it much smaller and powered by a small battery (one AAA or one CR2032). Even the Pi Zero is too large for the use case.

What component is a good fit for this task? (Microcontroller? RTC? I do not know what the correct category term is.)

My longer term goal is to make several of these small devices and place at different locations as visual cue reminders to perform a daily task. Like a spatially distributed daily checkbox list.

Required: 
As already noted, must be able to turn on/off LED based on time and button press. Time variation +/- 15 minutes accumulated over a week is ok, if I can fairly quickly reset back to the correct time manually once per week.

Also relevant:
- low cost (at most half the price of a raspberry pi zero)
- at least 1 week battery with one AAA battery

Not needed: 
wireless connection, quick way to change on/off times, bells and whistles.

Also relevant: I'm not experienced with microelectronics beyond some pretty basic Raspberry Pi use, so components that require advanced skills to program and/or advanced tools to work with are not a good fit.

Note: I have tried to research this but got overwhelmed by a lot of component terms (like RTC ICs) and possible dependencies on other components.

Edit: The use case is at evening in not very brightly lit rooms so even the kind of tiny power notification LEDs some laptops/smartphones have would probably be enough.

Comment: The TI MSP430 is probably one of the lowest powered devices for timing requirements, like this. But it's not the smallest device. Microchip makes some SOT23-6 PIC10 devices (PIC10LF322, for example.) The MSP430 supports watch crystals, which come in varying inherent accuracies and for which you may need to do some tweeking (not hard) to get them quite accurate over extended times. However, I'd recommend a CR2032 or similar as the battery supply. There are only very few MCUs that will operate at the range from 1.2 V to 1.5 V. You'd need a voltage boost chip for most MCUs.

Comment: How do you plan on setting the time and alarm times?

Comment: @jonk they are actually not that uncommon, but it's hard to drive a (visible light) LED with 1.5 V directly!

Comment: (@jonk had a jewlery project that sadly never saw the light of day, and found quite a few < 1.5V operational µCs with RTC)

Comment: @Mattman944 the times will be fixed for each device. So I will program/flash the fixed on/off time via whatever method the particular MCU uses.

Comment: You still need a method to set the time of day. If the device doesn't have a display, then I would use a temporary connection to a PC via a UART to set the time of day.

Comment: @Mattman944 Ok, I will learn to use UART.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach here is

- Use a microcontroller with integrated RTC
- Use a lithium coin cell, e.g. the CR2032, they have an incredible storage life, and you really don't need much power
- make sure to pulse the LED, which gives much perceived brightness per energy used

To that end, something like an ATMEL SAMD10 should have about 10 µA of standby current while still keeping the RTC on, and can run directly off the battery.

How to program that: good question; your 15min off per week is a pretty relaxed constrain (because: 15min/(60min/hr·24hr/d·7d)= 6.67% tolerance), so that reprogramming could be pretty rare. If you can just press a button that means "remind me exactly now, every 24hrs", that would probably be easiest to code :)

Comment: I'm in Europe and so far only find ATMEL SAMD10 with $20 shipping cost for 1 unit. Would e.g. MKE04Z8VTG4 (also an ARM Cortex-M0+ MCU) work similarly? Data sheet says RTC but there is so much info there that I don't grasp how comparable they are. https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MKE04P24M48SF0.pdf

Comment: `If you can just press a button that means "remind me exactly now, every 24hrs"`
 No, LED must turn on at same time (e.g. 17:00) daily independent of LED off time. Can the MCU do this logic?   
On power on: assume time 16:59:50 + start keeping time. At 17:00: do regular power mode + turn on LED + start button monitoring. At 22:00 or button press event: turn off LED + stop button monitoring + do low power mode. I could then once a week (or more seldom if time drift is small) manually pull and reinsert battery at 17:00 to resync the device.

Comment: no I meant you give the device a dedicated button that means "in 24h and every 24h after that, turn on the LED"? Would that make sense?

Comment: (an MCU can implement any algorithm: it's turing complete)

Comment: Ok, I understand now. But I do not want an extra button. Prefer: As soon as device gets battery power turn on LED. Turn off 5h later or on button press. Repeat pattern every 24h. Or is what you suggest simpler to do? If with extra button you mean a power reset button then our two ideas are the same I guess.

Comment: well, whether it resets the power or not is an "implementation detail" ;) What I'd be thinking of is probably more in the realm of "if the LED is on, push the button to turn it off; if the LED is off, and you hold down the button for 5 seconds, you program the device to turn the LED on in 24 hours"

Comment: Ok, I like that! :) I just have a lot to learn (get a MCU fit for the task, make the circuit, learn to use UART from raspberry to program the MCU, write the program) so am wary of extra features. Can I program the SAMD10 (or MKE04Z8VTG4 or similar ARM Cortex-M0) using only a raspberry pi or is extra hardware needed?

Comment: you usually don't program MCUs via UART :)

Comment: you can probably actually directly program them from the Raspberry pi by using a program to emulate a programmer device, let me check real quick

Comment: @rewan yes, you can do it without extra hardware (search for "raspberry pi openocd SWD programming"), but honestly: it's probably worth investing ~ 10€ into an "STLink v2" programmer clone; these are simple USB devices, so that you don't have to involve your Raspberry Pi at all but can directly work from your main laptop/desktop computer (which is probably more comfortable)

Comment: @rewan you'd start learning how to program an MCU by getting an "eval(uation) board" for that MCU. I think you'd do well if you started with [this](https://www.microchip.com/DevelopmentTools/ProductDetails/PartNO/ATSAMD10-XMINI) eval board for the SAMD10, which you can get [from these places](https://octopart.com/search?q=ATSAMD10-XMINI&currency=USD&specs=0). Advantage: it already comes with a programmer included! You can also use that programmer later on if you should build your own board.

Answer (score 0):

Pain will be the single AAA, 2 in series makes it much easier, due to not many chips that can go as low as 1V on supply voltage,

How I'm thinking you will have it connected:

RTC chip with an alarm function built in, connected to a low power micro, e.g. an attiny,

the RTC alarm output is setup with the flag mode instead of the short pulse, this way it has to be cleared by the micro before it will set that pin low, The led is switched by this pin,

You have 2 or more buttons on the device to set the time and to allow clearing the flag, these should be connected to inputs that can wake the micro from power-down,

If you still need 1 battery, at this power level, a bucket brigade converter may be one of the more efficient.

Edit: If you want to make it fancier, you could use a cheap E-Ink display that the micro updates when you change your setting time so you can at a glance tell if its set right, and have almost no current draw while idle

Comment: Don't use an attiny an RTC chip. You can buy plenty of microcontrollers that integrate an RTC, and work with < 1.5V, and use less power than an attiny.

Comment: (you're still very right about the power supply, though: a LED usually won't turn on very much with 1.5 V, so a step-up converter, like a really simple diode voltage multiplier fed by GPIO pins, might be a good approach)

Comment: In my past research the integrated RTC chips with alarm mode active used less power than the internal RTC circuit in a number of similar micro controllers, leaving this combination as the longer battery life solultion.

Comment: if you're using AAAs, you can run a typical Cortex-M0 for years in sleep mode, anyway: the self-discharge of alkaline batteries is worse than the current draw. The attiny really isn't very much an efficient device, by modern standards.